# Chain of responsibility pattern

Tags: python, design-patterns, python-2.x

```
class ReportFormat(object):
    PDF = 0
    TEXT = 1


class Report(object):
    """Strategy context."""

    def __init__(self, format_):
        self.title = 'Monthly report'
        self.text = ['Things are going', 'really, really well.']
        self.format_ = format_


class Handler(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.nextHandler = None

    def handle(self, request):
        self.nextHandler.handle(request)


class PDFHandler(Handler):

    def handle(self, request):
        if request.format_ == ReportFormat.PDF:
            self.output_report(request.title, request.text)
        else:
            super(PDFHandler, self).handle(request)

    def output_report(self, title, text):
        print '<html>'
        print '  <head>'
        print '    <title>%s</title>' % title
        print '  </head>'
        print '  <body>'
        for line in text:
            print '    <p>%s</p>' % line
        print '  </body>'
        print '</html>'


class TextHandler(Handler):

    def handle(self, request):
        if request.format_ == ReportFormat.TEXT:
            self.output_report(request.title, request.text)
        else:
            super(TextHandler, self).handle(request)

    def output_report(self, title, text):
        print 5*'*' + title + 5*'*'
        for line in text:
            print line


class ErrorHandler(Handler):

    def handle(self, request):
        print "Invalid request"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    report = Report(ReportFormat.TEXT)
    pdf_handler = PDFHandler()
    text_handler = TextHandler()

    pdf_handler.nextHandler = text_handler
    text_handler.nextHandler = ErrorHandler()

    pdf_handler.handle(report)
```

O/P:

> ```
> *****Monthly report*****
> Things are going
> really, really well.
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, this is abuse of the [Chain-of-responsibility Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern).  It is completely surprising that `pdf_handler.handle(report)` would generate a text report instead.

The Wikipedia example for Chain-of-responsibility is a logger.  As the message passes through the chain, each logger may choose to do something with it (write to standard output, send e-mail, etc.) depending on the verbosity level.

Another example of Chain-of-responsibility is the [filter mechanism in Apache HTTPD](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/filter.html).  Each input or output filter in the chain can alter the request or response.

Your use case is different: you only want to generate one kind of report.  For that, use a subtly different design: the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).  Basically, just do the simplest thing that could work:

- Each kind of handler defines a `handle(self, request)` method.
- If you want a text report, then call `TextReport().handle(request)`.

Comment: No, its not an abuse. See this [description](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/chain_of_responsibility)

Comment: Yes, it is abuse, as I just explained. As your article states, Chain of Responsibility "[avoids] coupling the sender of a request to its receiver by giving more than one object a chance to handle the request." But you have no reason to let multiple objects handle the request. I've given examples of where a chain _would_ be appropriate; your problem does not fit that pattern.

Comment: The request should be handled by any on object, read it again.

Comment: +1 I totally agree with your answer, but rereading both articles linked here I see the examples use the same design where each link has a reference to the next link in the chain. By moving the chain creation into a separate method, you don't realize that the first link in the chain is being referenced by clients directly. Clients think they have a generic `ReportHandler` when in reality they hold the `PDFHandler`.

Answer (score 4):

I would not use Chain of Responsibility to solve this problem. For every request, a single handler is chosen based on the same property: it's output format. For that you can use a simple dispatch table: a dict mapping each output format to its handler. There's no point asking each handler if it can handle the request.

**Update:** As usual, the [Portland Pattern Repository](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ChainOfResponsibilityPattern) has some good historical discussion of this pattern, specifically when not to use it:

> Do not use Chain of Responsibility when each request is only handled by one handler, or, when the client object knows which service object should handle the request.

**Note:** `Report` and `ReportFormat` are unchanged from the OP and omitted for brevity.

```
class ReportDispatcher(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reports = {}

    def add(self, report):
        self.reports[report.format] = report;

    def handle(self, request):
        report = self.reports[request.format_]
        if report:
            report.handle(request)
        else
            print "Invalid request"

class Handler(object):

    def __init__(self, format):
        self.format = format

    def handle(self, request):
        print "subclass responsibility"

class PDFHandler(Handler):

    def __init__(self):
        super(PDFHandler, self).__init__(ReportFormat.PDF)

    def handle(self, request):
        print '<html>'
        print '  <head>'
        print '    <title>%s</title>' % request.title
        print '  </head>'
        print '  <body>'
        for line in request.text:
            print '    <p>%s</p>' % line
        print '  </body>'
        print '</html>'

class TextHandler(Handler):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TextHandler, self).__init__(ReportFormat.TEXT)

    def handle(self, request):
        print 5*'*' + request.title + 5*'*'
        for line in request.text:
            print line

if __name__ == '__main__':
    reports = ReportDispatcher()
    reports.add(PDFHandler())
    reports.add(TextHandler())

    report = Report(ReportFormat.TEXT)
    reports.handle(report)
```

As you can see from the main method, sending a report request is completely decoupled from the various report handlers. Instead, the request is sent to the dispatcher which knows about the handlers.

Comment: Hi, your example is similar to the strategy pattern. In my example I just tried to show the use case of the command pattern, maybe my use case is not so clear. I think the main problem here is I am calling directly the concrete report object maybe if I put them is some container and then calling a method on the container may solve the issue.

Comment: maybe this link provides some more insight http://www.oodesign.com/chain-of-responsibility-pattern.html

Comment: @vivekpoddar Your choice of use case is probably the only real issue. See my small update.

Comment: Although the use case regarding request handling differs here. I myself will not use this pattern in the above case, it was because I was not finding some useful use case I implemented in the above scenario.